# If the prior distribution of $\lambda$ is a gamma distribution with mean 1.4 and std dev of .5 find the appropriate values and $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

If the prior distribution of $\lambda$ is a gamma distribution with mean of 1.4 and standard deviation of .5 with the form

$\pi(\lambda | \alpha, \beta)=\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \lambda^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta \lambda}$

What are the appropriate values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ based on the information provided about the prior mean and standard deviation.

Comment: What is the mean of a gamma random variable? What is the variance? You need to find these in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta.$